# Fix Android camera frame rate

Tags: android, camera

I'm looking to substantially lower and fix the framerate for video on an Android camera - I'm going to be treating it as a stream of still frames taken faster than the camera setting allows, but much slower than video.  As such, I'd like to change the framerate and keep it constant.

I know that setPreviewFpsRange(int, int) is the preferred technique, passing in the same min and max.  However, this doesn't establish a constant framerate in the face of things like lighting changes.  Given that I'm not trying to get an unsustainably high framerate (I'm actually aiming quite low), is there a way to ensure a constant rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you mention `setPreviewFpsRange()` in your question, I'll assume you can use the preview's resolution. In that case, you can work around the variable frame rate a bit by encoding the video yourself. Basically, run it at "normal" rate, and grab the frames as they come in to the [`PreviewCallback`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.PreviewCallback.html). Check the time since last frame, discard the ones you don't need. Then when you're done, use something like FFMPEG to encode to video.

This doesn't *guarantee* a perfectly constant rate, but you should be able to control it more *consistently* across devices, since various devices handle auto-changing the rate quite differently.

Of course, this could be quite storage intensive, since you are saving every frame separately, then encoding video, then deleting frames. If the videos you're interested in taking are somewhat short, this could be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks, this approach actually has a lot of potential. Storage intensive is probably something I can work around - I'm going to be shooting extremely lengthy video, but on a completely dedicated phone.  As such, I can have an extra SD card slotted in just for this and battery will probably be my primary hurdle.

Going by this solution I don't need a constant frame-rate - the goal was to keep from analyzing too many images, but checking timestamps to discard them should suffice.  This looks like a solid answer for me.

Comment: That's good. I wasn't sure if you'd be interested, since it adds a great deal of complexity compared to a typical "record video" approach, but I didn't think it would hurt to post.

Comment: @Geobits, so you mean save all preview frames in sd card and then encode them at the last step? if the resolution is 720 * 480, fps is 30, then the file size would be 720*480*3/2*30*10s(if the longest duration is 10s) = 150MB